# Jquery Mobile upgrade to 1.4 link button on header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I created an app using jquery mobile 1.3 however at the time i wanted to put a small image of the button on the right hand side of the header. all i needed it to do using jquery mobile version 1.3 was this

```
<a data-role="none" href="#ThisMap"><img src="../locaimages/System-Map-icon.png"  style="float:right;display:inline" /></a>
```

so before it used to look like this 
[image]

but now after changing to 1.4 it looks like this.
[image]

i try doing what they suggested in this post.
[Custom Header Buttons in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185862/custom-header-buttons-in-jquery-mobile)
but that does not seem to work. Can someone please set me straight. 
all i would like to do is have a small image as a button.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order to accomplish what i'm trying to accomplish i would need to do things a little different. I actually create the image as a button and listen to the click event of the image button and execute the next bit of code.
you can find more information on this post.
[Create image buttons in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441710/create-image-buttons-in-jquery-mobile)